# Unexpected result when C++ store element into std::vector from return value of function

Tags: c++, gcc, vector, compiler-optimization, compiler-bug

When the function involves reallocation, I found some compilers may save the address before the function call.  It leads the return value stored in the invalid address.

There is an example to explain behavior in above description.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector> 
using namespace std;

vector<int> A; 
int func() { 
    A.push_back(3);
    A.push_back(4);
    return 5; 
} 
int main() { 
    A.reserve(2);
    A.push_back(0);
    A.push_back(1);
    A[1] = func();
    printf("%d\n", A[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

There are some common C++ compiler, and the test result as follows.

- GCC(GNU Compiler Collection): Runtime Error or output `1`
- Clang: output `5`
- VC++: output `5`

Is it undefined behavior?

Comment: See the description of the assignment operator at least in the C++ 2014 Standard.

Comment: _"When the function involves relocation, I found some compilers may save the address before the function call"_ - none of those things mean what you seem to think they mean. This isn't anything to do with dynamic linking. "When the function involves _reallocation_" would be accurate.

Comment: Good point. Reallocation somehow implies relocation (create new space, move stuff over), but using reallocation would be clearer here, if that is what the original author really meant.

Comment: @Useless what he meant was obvious enough, and nothing to do with linking. He means if the vector contents is relocated (reallocation could in theory leave the data unmoved, were a library to use `realloc` behind the scenes), and that the compiler may have kept the address of the data in a register around the calls to `push_back`. I've encountered the bug^Wissue he's talking about before now, so you could claim I'm biased, but ...

Comment: I know what OP meant after re-reading, but there's no harm telling people the correct names for things (or what the words they used actually mean). It's all useful information.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The behaviour is undefined in all C++ versions before C++17. The simple reason is that the two sides of the assignment operator can be evaluated in any order:

- Assuming `A[1]` is evaluated first, you get an `int&` referring to the second element of `A` at that point.
- Then, the `func()` is evaluated, which can reallocate the storage for the vector, leaving the previously retrieved `int&` a dangling reference.
- Finally, the assignment is performed, writing to unallocated storage. Since the standard allocators cache memory, the OS often won't catch this error.

Only in C++17, the [special rule 20](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) for the assignment was made:

> In every simple assignment expression E1=E2 and every compound
>   assignment expression E1@=E2, every value computation and side-effect
>   of E2 is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of
>   E1

With C++17, `A[1]` must be evaluated after the call to `func()`, which then provides defined, reliable behaviour.

Comment: Binaries made with GCC do not crash if `-std=c++17` is used. Maybe the wording in C++17 has changed?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It did.  operators have to respect associativity

Comment: I think it should say "which can reallocate the storage for the vector" instead

Comment: @Slava, I wrote the above under the assumption that `reserve()` guarantees the exact size, but it seems to guarantee a minimal size instead. I remembered that part wrongly.

Comment: Maybe C++17 changed some rules about evaluation order, which can be found in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: As per item 20 on the cppreference page @MorrisYang linked, the code's behavior is not undefined in C++17 so if you could edit your answer to show that it would be complete.

Answer (score -5):

If you check the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), under "Iterator Invalidation", you'll see that `push_back()` may invalidate *every iterator* if it changes capacity, since it would have to reallocate memory. Remember that, for an `std::vector`, a pointer is a valid iterator as well. Because `push_back()` may or may not reallocate, and you have no way of knowing if it will, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Pointers (or references) and iterators are separate, with separate rules. If you look at other containers you'll see cases where one will invalidate but not the other.

Comment: Sure, but this is not one of those cases. A pointer to T satisfies all the requirements of vector<T>::iterator.

Comment: Just because a pointer *can be* an iterator, doesn't make it an iterator. In the case of `std::vector` iterators and references are invalidated at the same time, but that doesn't mean they're the same. This is the sort of answer that can confuse people.

Comment: If I edited my answer to say specifically that "for an `std::vector` a pointer is a valid iterator", would that be satisfactory?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/ is more explicit: *If a reallocation happens, all iterators, pointers and references related to the container are invalidated.*

Comment: No, because *it's not an iterator*. End of discussion.

Comment: Practical workaround: `reserve()` space in your `vector`.

Comment: @MarkRansom from n4284, "Note: For example, the type "pointer to int" is a contiguous iterator" ...

Comment: @WillCrawford I'm not denying that a pointer is a perfectly valid iterator implementation, and some early versions of `vector` worked that way. But try comparing a pointer to `v.end()` and tell me how that works out.

Comment: Ha! No, fair enough … I’d still argue that some parts of the standard give the impression that T* "ought" to work as an iterator (e.g. `template <class T, size_t N> constexpr T* begin(T (&array)[N]) noexcept;` … Returns: `array`)